# Alternative to IETester

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, ietester

I was wondering if anyone knew of any alternatives to IE Tester. I am getting some differences between my actual XP IE6 vm and my IETester. So I am looking for something that is a little more accurate than IETester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the options are somewhat limited.

You can use VMWare with a Windows XP (or lower) install to test IE6

You can use VirtualPC (free) with a (free) [XP/IE6 image from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en)

You **used** to be able to use Spoon.net to run just the browser via a plugin in Firefox/whatever

You can try MultipleIE's but IE6 **will break** and not work if IE8 is installed locally

Or if you are really lucky, you can DROP IE6 support!

Comment: I wish i could drop ie6 support but the company still brings in a good amount of money on ie6 users even though they are at about 5% of our total traffic. Well thats what i thought the answers would be I guess I will just stick with  ie tester thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I use expression super preview.  It's good for layout bugs, but unfortunately it is useless for script testing

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the one page you can use [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) for free or sign up for a small fee. They have been very good in the past when I have experienced the same issues with IE Tester not being 100% correct mainly with JavaScript problems.